# Index not created

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I have a document with an index defined.

```
/** @ODM\Document */
class Stat
{
    /** @ODM\Id(strategy="NONE", type="int") */
    private $id;

    /** @ODM\Field(type="string") */
    private $period;

    /** @ODM\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Player") */
    private $player;

    /** @ODM\Field(type="string") @ODM\Index */
    private $statType;
```

However, when I look at the indexes created in the collection, the only index is the _id.

To save the document I'm doing:

```
$stat = new Documents\Stat();

$stat->setId(1);
$stat->setPlayer($player);
$stat->setPeriod(1);
$stat->setStatType('goal');

$dm->persist($stat);
$dm->flush();
```

Is there something else I'm not doing?

Answer (score 4):

Indexes are not created (nor ensured if they're in sync with mapping) during normal ODM usage.

If you're using Symfony then solving problem is easy, just run `doctrine:mongodb:schema:create` command from Symfony's console (and if you're using other framework, look for equivalent as command itself is provided by ODM).

If you want to control indexes from your code you can use [`SchemaManager`](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/b69fa10d03f7d5d9fbf397cf5491a407059ba3d6/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/SchemaManager.php#L55) which provides an API to control "schema" directly (you can also control indexes on per-document basis). Obtaining it is easy: `$sm = $dm->getSchemaManager();`.

Comment: I tried the odm:schema:create and I still get all my collections without Indexes.

Comment: No. I got:  
  
`Created dbs for all classes  
Created collections for all classes  
Created indexes for all classes`  
  
No specific list of documents

Comment: Try running the command with `--class` and specifying your class

Comment: It is indeed the correct answer! Futher more : **doctrine:mongodb:schema:create** create and also update the mongodb schema and **doctrine:mongodb:schema:update** can be used to update it.

Answer (score 1):

// AppBundle/Document

```
    namespace AppBundle\Document;

    use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;
    use Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\Validator\Constraints\Unique as MongoDBUnique;

    /**
    * @MongoDB\Document(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ProduitRepository")
    * @MongoDBUnique(fields="$noProduit")
    */
    class Produit
    {
      /**
       * @MongoDB\Id
       */
       protected $id;

      /**
       * @MongoDB\String
       * @MongoDB\UniqueIndex(order="asc")
       */
       protected $noProduit;

       /**
        * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
        */
       protected $libelle;

      // getter and setter
    }
```

// AppBundle/Controller

```
   $dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
   $dm->getSchemaManager()->ensureIndexes();
```

schema and database will be created automatically when you run your app.
For more info 
[visit this link](http://blog.servergrove.com/2010/10/07/creating-indexes-for-your-doctrine-odm-documents-with-symfony-2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @ODM\Document
 * @ODM\Indexes({
 *   @ODM\Index(keys={"statType"="asc"}),
 *   @ODM\UniqueIndex(keys={"period"="asc"})//For example unique index
 * })
 */
class Stat
{
}
```

Then if you use symfony run `php bin/console doctrine:mongodb:schema:create`